# Why does a StackoverflowException terminate the entire process instead of just the single thread?

Tags: .net

Since every thread owns a private stack why just not inform another thread about the `StackoverflowException` and let die the thread, especially if it is a background worker thread?

Comment: What thread would you like to inform, and how? It's really hard to write a reliable exception handler in the face of a `StackOverflowException`, so this would require some sort of magic in the form of a pre-registered forwarder. That's an interesting feature, but every feature needs to justify its cost to design, implement and document. This one probably doesn't. Consider that an aborted thread is usually a great way to destabilize the entire process anyway -- if the stack overflow was due to a harmless mistake like endless recursion, you could have probably prevented it.

Comment: It is not automatic, the [CLR host decides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164395(v=vs.110).aspx).  You are not going to find a lot of them that turn FAIL_StackOverflow into meh.  Well, hopefully not.  Too much meh in .NET 1.x is the basic reason why the OS is called Vista and not Windows.NET.  Maybe that was a Good Thing, given its popularity :)

Answer (score 3):

Any exception will tear down the process if  it  makes it  back to the root without being caught. A `StackOverflowException` *cannot* be caught (from .NET 2.0 onwards). Hence: boom.

Basically, don't cause a `StackOverflowException`. Add counters to recursive code, for example, or re-write it using a non-recursive implementation (perhaps a  loop over a `Queue<T>` or `Stack<T>` of pending items).

Comment: "Basically, don't cause a StackOverflowException". Thats right, but today software is made up of dozens to hundreds of (NuGet) packages and you don't have control of all of them. In my case it seems that EntityFramework sometimes freaks out without any chance of reproducing it -- the call stack I've seen once in VS even was not long at all (~50). Attaching a debugger (VS 2015) when this Exception occurs never was successful, it just attaches and immediately ends the debug session + process without any break.

Comment: @springy76: you could try using `AppDomain.UnhandledException` and [`HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute) to set up a handler you can breakpoint. (This will not prevent the process from terminating, but you may have more luck debugging it that way.)

Comment: For completeness, if you absolutely positively *must* run code that could throw exceptions like this and you *must* have a process that does not terminate, your only recourse is to host the CLR yourself and apply a custom policy with [`ICLRPolicyManager::SetActionOnFailure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms164395) to unload the AppDomain instead. I doubt you want to go that far, as it's a ton of work for little gain, but I'm still throwing it out there. In practice, isolating such code in its own process that could crash is probably easier, if still painful.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I tried `Debugger.Break()` in `AppDomain.UnhandledException` in combination with `legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy` in web.config but I only got "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException." (twice) in console output and the process is already gone.

Comment: @springy76: I doubt `legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy` works from a `web.config`, but it appears the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` documentation is wrong as well: applying `HandleProcessCorruptedState` and `SecurityCritical` should allow the event handler to see the exception, but in my tests, this is not the case. Your only recourse in this case is to set/allow a just-in-time debugger, which *will* be invoked.

Comment: @JeroenMostert sorry for typo, there is no web.config but an app.config since it's a console application.